# UnExpected 404 error in Hibernate Spring Project

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

---

I am developing hibernate spring project which works fine untill i add Webflow dependencyin pom.XML .Anybody help me......

## Execption

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.needsRefresh(Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/InjectionMetadata;Ljava/lang/Class;)Z
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findPersistenceMetadata(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:384)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessMergedBeanDefinition(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyMergedBeanDefinitionPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:908)
```

## web.xml

```
<web-app>
    <filter>
<filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
<filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
 </filter-mapping>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
        <listener-class>org.h2.server.web.DbStarter</listener-class>
    </listener>
  <servlet>
  <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
  <servletclass>
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servletclass>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name> 
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
   <display-name>Click buy</display-name>

 </web-app>
```

## Dispatcher

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:webflow="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config/spring-webflow-config-2.3.xsd
        ">
<mvc:annotation-driven></mvc:annotation-driven>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.controller"></context:component-scan>
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
<property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/"></property>
<property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
</bean>
<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
              <property name="maxUploadSize" value="10240000" />
 </bean>
<mvc:resources location="resources/Images/" mapping="resources/Images/**"/>

    </beans>
```

### Note:

I am having final review with in a week.so please help me guys.And i am a beginner.Please let me know wheather i did any mistakes in it..........

Comment: It sounds like the Web flow thingy is depending on another jar

Comment: Let me know how to fix it

Comment: Share the pom.xml. check versions of the other  spring stuff there. There could be mismatches. I haven't used webflow myself though

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43187799/404-error-in-associate-mapping